# How to delete greyed out Bookmarks and Recents?

Tags: panel

I had an external HD go out on me, so I switched to a new HD. However Blender is still looking for the old HD in bookmarks. I can't select it to delete it. Any ideas?

I realize the image below is recents and not bookmarks, just replicating the problem on another computer.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can delete greyed out Bookmarks but not Recent. Recent will just go away after a while or you could delete all of them by clicking **X** button next to the list.

To clear bookmarks list click on **arrow button** next to the list and choose **Cleanup**.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2):

Just edit the `bookmarks.txt` inside the Blender's config folder :)
For me, in Linux, is under `/home/{user}/.config/blender/{version}/config/bookmarks.txt`

[image: blende config folder]

Once deleted, just close and reopen Blender ;)